# Show/Hide view in xCode in the same file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I show and hide a view using xCode in the same file .xib?

Answer (score 2):

**Progmatically** set YES to hide view else NO

```
yourView.hidden=YES;
```

Or if you want to do it in **.xib** file then in your **attribute inspector** in **view** section, under **drawing** checkmark hidden to hide the view

Is this what you meant?

Comment: pleas write example about this

Comment: You want example for programmatically or using interface builder?

Comment: programatically and best of if you can programmatically and using interface

Comment: actually both are given above... but specifically if you hav a UIImageView imageView then you can hide it doing this imageView.hidden=YES;

Comment: i want same exmaple:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936576/show-and-hide-view-in-xcode.

Comment: but i can't understand...pleas help me

Comment: Aw the sample you saw doesnt hide the view. it simple changes the X position of the view to move it in and out of the visible part of the screen

Answer (score 1):

Push View Controller A onto a UINavigationController to begin with. When the user clicks on the button in view A, push View Controller B onto the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the alpha value with `[myView setAlpha:0.0f];`

This can be used inside an animation block if you want to provide a fade effect - the alpha value will change over the duration of the animation.